# PHP - Storing session username or ID preferred?

Tags: php, security, session

I'm just wondering, for a PHP session, would it be preferred to store a session variable containing a logged in user's ID or username?

At the moment it stores the username, whereas would ID be safer because to potential "hackers", they may not know which user the ID correlates to?

Comment: Seems like an ID would be the smarter choice, but not because it's safer, but because that is most likely the primary key in the database.

Comment: @Devon that's also my sort of thinking. I've been using usernames forever, however it recently occurred to me that IDs are easier to work with.

Comment: From a "hacking" point of view, this makes no difference. If a hacker is trying to impersonate another user, he will use the username if your session stores the username and the id if your session uses ids.

Comment: @zuc0001: you can save both, ID for working with database (select my comments, articles, profile, ...), name for showing info in website (logged as: XY). In sessions often have all (more) info about user, except password, of course.

Comment: @panther, I have a class which grabs all the critical user information on page load. So if I feed it the ID, it will grab the username, email, and all relevant information automatically for use. So I don't think I'd need a session for that :). Thanks for your point of view though!

Comment: @zuc0001: of course, but you call this class everytime you need user info? Better way is to call it once, save into session and every next time take data from session instead of database :-) You didn't mention that before, I didn't know how you do it in your app.

Comment: @panther Oh! I never thought of doing it that way. That would decrease load on the SQL server dramatically instead of grabbing it each time the page loads! I call the class each time the page LOADS, however it can also be used for grabbing user information for a number of users (input ID into the class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP sessions work by giving an "opaque" cookie to users - that is, the cookie is just a number, and the actual data is stored on your server. When a user sends you the session cookie, PHP looks up the number in a table to retrieve the data you've stored for that user.

This means that it is impossible, without access to your server, for anyone listening over the network to figure out what the session cookie actually means. They would need the table stored on your server. So it really doesn't matter if you store an ID number or a username in the session: if they have enough access to see what's in the session, then they could probably just look up the username based on the ID number anyway.